# SQL to find last alpha value in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find last alhpa value in a string .

My string will be like below :

```
  thj_ujk_008j_1  
  tky_ujk_098f_*/_2
```

My result should be :

```
  j  
  f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `regexp_replace()` and select out the matched final alpha value which you are seeking:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '.*([a-zA-Z]).*', '\1')
from yourTable
```

This regex appears to be working properly when tested using Regex101:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kN9mC3/1)